# offline access deprecation - whats the alternative

Tags: facebook, offline

As per the developer road map - offline access is being deprecated. So whats the alternative ?
I know we can get extended token that will expire in 60 days, but how about the offline access ? The documentation isnt clear about weather this token works on or not when user is not logged in.

See [FB.logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) It says calling FB.logout will invalidate any existing token unless you have offline_access permission, How does this affect to new extended token ? If it invalidates the extended token as well, is there any alternative.

The old offline_access permission would let the app make calls to graph API even when user isn't logged in, does the extended token work in same way ? if not what's the alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no way to get requests on behalf of users.

Answer (score 0):

You're app will also be vulnerable to the user logging out. We are still in under the temporary offline_access but as soon as the user logs out of their browser session on facebook the credential generated at the time is no longer valid. It's a huge bummer for async apps.